# How to show a total counter bar using indicatif with async?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I try to use the [indicatif](https://crates.io/crates/indicatif) crate to show several progress bars of sub-tasks together with one progress bar counting all finished tasks. Here is my code:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
indicatif = "0.15.0"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
futures = "0.3"
```

```
//! main.rs
use std::time::Duration;
use futures::{StreamExt, stream::futures_unordered::FuturesUnordered};
use indicatif::{MultiProgress, ProgressBar, ProgressStyle};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let m = MultiProgress::new();
    let sty = ProgressStyle::default_bar()
        .template("[{elapsed_precise}] {bar:40.cyan/blue} {pos:>7}/{len:7} {msg}")
        .progress_chars("##-");
    let total_pb = m.add(ProgressBar::new(3));
    total_pb.set_style(sty.clone());
    let mut futs = FuturesUnordered::new();
    let durations = [15u64, 8, 3];
    let mut pb_cnt = 0usize;
    for &duration in durations.iter() {
        let pb = m.insert(pb_cnt, ProgressBar::new(256));
        pb_cnt += 1;
        pb.set_style(sty.clone());
        let total_pb = total_pb.clone();
        let task = tokio::spawn(async move {
            for i in 0i32..256 {
                pb.set_message(&format!("item #{}", i + 1));
                pb.inc(1);
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(duration)).await;
            }
            pb.finish_with_message("done");
            total_pb.inc(1);
        });
        futs.push(task);
    }
    while let Some(result) = futs.next().await {
        result?;
    }
    total_pb.finish_with_message("done");
    m.join()?;
    // tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || m.join().unwrap() ).await.unwrap(); 

    Ok(())
}
```

`total_pb` is the bar counting all finished tasks.

The problem is that no progress bars appear on the console until all work has finished already, only showing me their final states. I tried to follow suggestions in [this issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/indicatif/issues/212#issuecomment-727201401) and [this issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/indicatif/issues/125#issuecomment-635092250), but there are a couple problems:

1. I tried to insert `let m = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || m.join().unwrap());` as in the code above but it doesn't work.
2. `total_pb` won't finish until all tasks finish, which means `m.join()` cannot be called right after each spawned task as an synchronization as suggested in the first issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different solutions, you need to call `m.join()` on an active blocking thread. Either you do it in your main thread, and so you need to move your:

```rust
while let Some(result) = futs.next().await {
    result?;
}
```

somewhere else, like spawn a task.

Or you spawn a blocking thread and just await it at the end (probably the best). So just do:

```
let handle_m = tokio::task::spawn_blocking(move || m.join().unwrap()); // add this line
while let Some(result) = futs.next().await {
    result?;
}
total_pb.finish_with_message("done");
handle_m.await?; // don't forget to await your handle
```

Note that contrary to your try #1, you must spawn the blocking thread BEFORE await your result...

There was 2 examples that could help you in the future [tokio.rs](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/indicatif/blob/main/examples/tokio.rs) [multi.rs](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/indicatif/blob/main/examples/multi.rs).